# How to get an alert message containing html and a yes/no-button in google spreadsheet that stops executing the script till user has clicked yes or no?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm sending html emails from a google spreadsheet, and for a certain group, I want to first see a preview before sending it. The script to send the emails can be invoked by clicking a menu item on the spreadsheet. So I want to create a pop-up that contains the html message and a button to send the email yes or no. This is the case for multiple emails, so the script has to wait for user input before showing the next email.

I can use the alert function from the Ui-class, problem is that it only accepts a string for the message, not html. But the alert does stop code execution till the user gives input.

The other option is showModelDialog function from the Ui-class, here I can give html as a parameter, but the google-apps-script does not stop executing, so the result is that I will only see the pop-up for the last email.

The alert function is not an option because I can't give html as a parameter, so showModelDialog is the best choice. Possible not-so-pretty-solutions that I found using showModelDialog, are using the sleep function from the class Utilities between each pop-up or only sending one email each time the function is invoked.

Is there a solution where I can show a pop-up with the html email and the apps script stops executing till it receives input from the user?

Comment: At the point where the dialog box is shown, break up your function into two parts.  Put everything after the dialog box in a new function, then call that function from the dialog box.

Comment: @sandy-good It's a possible solution but will require a lot of code refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

It can be accomplished with `showModelDialog` itself.
You can put the function to send the mail in a function say **sendMail**.

Now add a button to call that function on `onclick` event.

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Send" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

For more info refer
[Custom Dialogs in Google Apps Script](http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/drivebunny/custom-dialogs-in-google-apps-script/)

[Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#methods)

Comment: How you propose it, it doesn't work because I will only see the pop-up for the last message (since code keeps executing and pop-ups keep appearing). As @sandy-good suggests, I can break the function up where the pop-up is the ending of first part and when the users clicks, the following part starts, but this will require a lot of refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

`ui.prompt` seems to be a good workaround for this case

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.prompt('Email confirmation', 'Are you sure to send the mail?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

 if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
   Logger.log('The user responded positively');
   // call the function to send mail here
 } else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.NO) {
   Logger.log('The user gave negative response');
   // Do some cleanup?
 } else {
   Logger.log('The user clicked the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
 }
```

As functions to send mail is called inside `if else` condition which requires response to be evaluated, you can make sure it won't get executed.

Comment: I want to preview the html message in the pop-up, I don't see how I can do this with prompt. (it only accepts a string for the message)