# HTML possible in GoogleScript ui.alert

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using this code to create an alert in Google Sheets.

```
var message = "<br>Extra hours detected in rows: "
if(blankRows.length && blankRows2.length){
var response = ui.alert('Alert', "Extra images detected in rows: " + blankRows.join(', ') + message + blankRows2.join(', '), ui.ButtonSet.OK)
```

The <br> in message does not result in a line break but it actually displays as "<br>".
I saw that HTML does not work in ui.alert and I was wondering how I could get this to display correctly.

Comment: please provide more information, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try a '\n'..................

Comment: Related : [How to get an alert message containing html and a yes/no-button in google spreadsheet that stops executing the script till user has clicked yes or no?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36109504/1595451)

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `<br>` with `\n`.

User interfaces created with `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` do not support displaying HTML (`<br>`), but they do support using the Javascript line feed escape sequence (`\n`). More information about Javascript escape sequences [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes).

Using one `\n` will produce a line break in the dialogue. Also, they can be chained together: using two consecutively (`\n\n`) will produce a blank line, and using `\n\n\n` will produce two blank lines.

Comment: A little bit more explanation of what the difference between </br> and /n is will make you answer great. At the moment it is in the low quality queue, and is subject for deletion.